# UPDATE SQLITE FUNCTION WITH JAVASCRIPT NOT WORK

Tags: javascript, sqlite

i write this function for update records in a SQLite table, it not work, i not undestand why, thx

```
    function UpdateValues() {

    var id=document.getElementById("id").value;
    var mydata=document.getElementById("CommonName").value;
    var mydata2=document.getElementById("location").value;
    var mydata3=document.getElementById("datte").value;
    var mydata4=document.getElementById("Observations").value;



    var db = openDatabase('birdsdata1','1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {      
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS birdstabla1 (RegNum INTEGER 

PRIMARY KEY, CommonName CHAR(17), location CHAR(32), datte         CHAR(10), 

Observations CHAR(90))');

tx.executeSql('UPDATE birdstabla1 SET (location, Observations) VALUES (?, ?) 

WHERE RegNum=?', [mydata, mydata2, id], functerr);

    });
    }
```

Comment: 'it not work'? Do you get an error message? What happens?

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of errors in your code, but the one that makes it fail is that your `UPDATE` statement uses a wrong syntax.
Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE birdstabla1' +
              ' SET location = ?, Observations = ?' +
              ' WHERE RegNum = ?',
              [mydata2, mydata4, id]);
```